# Environment variables not visible in shell script executed using popen in c

Tags: c, bash, shell, scripting, popen

Can somebody help on this:

I'm executing shell script using popen in c program. Something like this:

```
fd = popen("script1", "r");
```

---

script1 code is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
source script2     #loading another script2

EXE_SOMETHING   #Function call from script2

//Do something....
```

---

script2 code is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
function SET_ENV()
{
    oraenv <<-EOF
    SID NAME
    EOF
}

function EXE_SOMETHING()
{
    SET_ENV
    //Executing sql query using sqlplus to get output from database.
}
```

---

My problem is i'm not getting env variables in EXE_SOMETHING which are being set by SET_ENV function, due to which I'm getting sqlplus command not found.

Comment: This could be related to what exactly `script2` is doing within `EXE_SOMETHING()`. Generally some environment variables are tied to the process/session, and the parts of `EXE_SOMETHING()` that need them (e.g. other `popen` calls or the like) would be loading into a fresh environment where those environment variables aren't present. Can you be more specific about the contents of `SET_ENV()` and `EXE_SOMETHING()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `oraenv` to modify the current shell environment, you must invoke it with `. oraenv`; otherwise the environment changes will be made in a subshell.

This is explained in the Oracle docs. Also see the documentation for the shell `.` command, which runs a script inside the current execution context rather than in a subshell.